# (Python): DataFrames add a total row that is the sum of only one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a a set of DataFrames and would like to add an a total row that sums only one of the columns (example table below)

I can add a total column with `df.loc['Total']= df.sum()` or even `df.loc['Total'] = [df[x].sum() for x in df.columns]`, however I need all columns except A to show blank and am having some issues with the syntax.

```
Item    A   B   C   D   E   F
1       1   2   3   4   5   6
2       5   10  15  20  25  30
3       10  20  30  40  50  60
4       5   15  25  35  45  55
Total   21
```

Any help is appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you need select column for sum and then specify column for output:

```
df.loc['Total', 'A']= df['A'].sum()
print (df)
       Item     A     B     C     D     E     F
0       1.0   1.0   2.0   3.0   4.0   5.0   6.0
1       2.0   5.0  10.0  15.0  20.0  25.0  30.0
2       3.0  10.0  20.0  30.0  40.0  50.0  60.0
3       4.0   5.0  15.0  25.0  35.0  45.0  55.0
Total   NaN  21.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Replace `NaN` to empty space is possible, but get mixed types - numeric with strings and some functions should failed:

```
df.loc['Total'] = df[['A']].sum().reindex(df.columns, fill_value='')
print (df)
      Item   A   B   C   D   E   F
0        1   1   2   3   4   5   6
1        2   5  10  15  20  25  30
2        3  10  20  30  40  50  60
3        4   5  15  25  35  45  55
Total       21
```

If need append values to 2 columns need assign list of values:

```
df.loc[len(df), ['Item','A']]= ['Total', df['A'].sum()]
print (df)
    Item     A     B     C     D     E     F
0      1   1.0   2.0   3.0   4.0   5.0   6.0
1      2   5.0  10.0  15.0  20.0  25.0  30.0
2      3  10.0  20.0  30.0  40.0  50.0  60.0
3      4   5.0  15.0  25.0  35.0  45.0  55.0
4  Total  21.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: This is great. Can I possibly use this method to get sum of multiple columns? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using `append`

```
In [3884]: s = pd.Series({'Item': 'Total', 'A': df['A'].sum()}, 
                         index=df.columns).fillna('')

In [3885]: df.append(s, ignore_index=True)
Out[3885]:
    Item   A   B   C   D   E   F
0      1   1   2   3   4   5   6
1      2   5  10  15  20  25  30
2      3  10  20  30  40  50  60
3      4   5  15  25  35  45  55
4  Total  21
```

Returns a copy for ease

---

Details

```
In [3886]: df
Out[3886]:
   Item   A   B   C   D   E   F
0     1   1   2   3   4   5   6
1     2   5  10  15  20  25  30
2     3  10  20  30  40  50  60
3     4   5  15  25  35  45  55

In [3887]: s
Out[3887]:
Item    Total
A          21
B
C
D
E
F
dtype: object
```